# How to prepopulate a ModelForm in the django template

Tags: django, django-forms

I am new to Django.
I am trying to create a form at 'example.com/contacts/10/edit' that allows you to edit the details of a contact and then bring you to the detail page of that contact (example.com/contacts/10). 10 in these instances is the default pk.

I have succeeded in displaying a form that edits the contact in the database, but the form is empty in the template and I cannot work out how to populate the form with the data from the database.

The ModelForm I am using - AddForm() - is the same that I use to add a new contact

Here is my code, there is probably some redundant stuff in here so please bear with me. All help is appreciated.

views.py

```
def EditContact(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Contact, id=pk)
    if request.POST:
        form = AddForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contacts/')

    else:
        form = AddForm()

    return render(request, 'contacts/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

form in template:

```
<form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <table>

            <p> {{ form.as_ul }}</p>

    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

Also I have recently read about generic editing views, maybe someone can tell me if they would be more suitable for what I am trying to achieve - that is, to add, edit and remove contacts from the database. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already are doing it in the `request.POST` block.

You would have to send in the `instance` argument in the else block too

```
def EditContact(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Contact, id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST': #It is better to explicitly check for method instead of the dictionary
        form = AddForm(request.POST, instance=instance) #No need of the "or None" here
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contacts/')    
    else:
        form = AddForm(instance=instance) #Here is the change

    return render(request, 'contacts/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: And you should drop the `or None`: you're in request.POST, there is no possibility that it is None.